# Link object is not supported on free connection using Advantage Database

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I'm developing a program using vb.net under VS2017 and ADS v11.1 on Visual Foxpro free tables with adsDataAdapter.

I want to copy records from a current table into a history table:

```
INSERT INTO
  c:\data\hinv.dbf
SELECT
  *
FROM c:\data\cinv.dbf WHERE [balance] = 0.00
```

I get the error:

```
The requested object was not found. c:\data\hinv Link object is not supported on free connection. Table name: dbf
```

The connection string includes

```
Data Source: c:\data\; TableType=VFP; LockMode=COMPATIBLE; ServerType=LOCAL
```

The connection works perfectly for SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE commands not using a subquery, for example

```
INSERT INTO
  c:\data\hinv.dbf
(
    [field1]
  , [field2]
)
VALUES
(
    value1
  , value2
)
```

will work with no problem.  I've tried the SAP community but received no response, and I've searched the net every way I can think of.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try doing it simply (since you've already got the Data Source configured)? `INSERT INTO hinv SELECT * FROM cinv`

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: Set your server type back to VFP, and try using `[C:\Data\cinv.dbf] c` and `[C:\Data\hinv.dbf] h` for the table names.

Answer (score 0):

ADS is confused by the dot notation of the table you are selecting from.

Here is a similar post:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/3294/sql-selection-from-dbf

ADS thinks you are selection from a table named `dbf` on a server link named `c:\data\hinv`.

You probably have to set the table type from `VFP` to `CDX` for ADS to recognize the filename as a table name.

Comment: I had seen that solution but was concerned since the specification of CDX refers to foxpro table structure, not visual foxpro table structure - and there are differences. Nonetheless I tried this solution, and it almost worked.

Comment: So I changed the connection string to reference TableType=CDX and tried this command string:  INSERT into c:\data\hinv Select * FROM c:\data\cinv.dbf where [balance] = 0.00  (note removing the first .dbf reference but not the second) - I got the following error:  The requested object was not found. c:\data\cinv - link object is not supported on free connection. Table name: dbf.  Clearly the error moved from hinv to cinv.  Almost there.

Comment: So I followed through with this command string: INSERT into c:\data\hinv Select * FROM c:\data\cinv where [balance] = 0.00  but received the following error: Corrupt table.  Make sure you are not attempting to open a DBF with an ADT table type or vice versa.  c:\data\cinv.dbf Table name: c:\data\cinv.  The error is still on the second table (the select from table) however now ADS can't recognize the table as a VFP table.  Sort of a catch-22.