# Using NHibernate with SAP Advantage Database Server 12

Tags: nhibernate, advantage-database-server

I'm currently trying to make NHibernate work with SAP's Advantage Database Server 12. Unfortunately, there is not much information around this database server in the internet, but in this case, I have to use it to access an existing database.

So I tried to set up a simple test project first which adds "Students" in a Student table, following this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_basic_orm.htm

As for the ADS, I found a driver and dialect here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhibernate-development/s7HLs-aEXDk

I've set up a table and this code:

```html
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "data source=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads;ServerType=local; TableType=ADT; Shared=True; LockMode=COMPATIBLE";
                x.Driver<AdvantageDatabaseServerDriver>();
                x.Dialect<AdvantageDatabaseServer8Dialect>();
                x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
            });

            cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var sefact = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            using (var session = sefact.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    //perform database logic 
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            using (var session = sefact.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var student1 = new Students
                    {
                        ID = 1,
                        FirstMidName = "Allan",
                        LastName = "Bommer"
                    };

                    var student2 = new Students
                    {
                        ID = 2,
                        FirstMidName = "Jerry",
                        LastName = "Lewis"
                    };

                    session.Save(student1);
                    session.Save(student2);
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

But it keeps throwing this exception at the first write attempt:

```html
NHibernate: INSERT INTO C:\Users\ad\Downloads\REFERENCE\Students.adt (LastName, FirstMidName) VALUES (?, ?); select NEWIDSTRING() from system.iota;p0 = 'Glenn' [Type: String (-1:0:0)], p1 = 'Allan' [Type: String (-1:0:0)]
Exception thrown: 'Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException' in NHibernate.dll
```

Is there anything wrong with the dialect maybe? I really appreciate any help on this, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way for you to retrieve what the actual error text is inside the AdsException class? Otherwise it is just pure speculation what is wrong.

Comment: One thing that could be wrong is the table type, could you post your connection string? See this question for what happens with a wrong table type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934326/link-object-is-not-supported-on-free-connection-using-advantage-database

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your reply.
Here's my connection string: "data source=C:\\REFERENCE;ServerType=local; TableType=ADT; Shared=True; LockMode=COMPATIBLE". Table name is written in the XML, I also tried remote server (connection string works fine with other apps).

The ADS error, if I put the SQL statement into the Data Architect is:
"poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2218;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]The variable is not found: p0 -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 137 (line: 2 column: 40)".

Seems like the variables p0, p1 are the problem?!

Comment: Some more information on the error 2218 I've got from the Data Architect:
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/mergedProjects/adserror/err2xxx/2218_variable_not_found.htm

Comment: Not necessarily, Data Architect uses the Delphi components which support a different parameter syntax than the ADO.NET driver. You have to somehow catch the AdsException in your application to get the actual error message.

Comment: I put everything in a try/catch block and caught: "Error 5111: The parameter name specified was invalid for the statement. p0".
And I found this: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/Content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=070813-1930
Do you know how to alter the SQL statement as they recommend? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments the problem is this:

NHibernate with the grammar you are using emits this code:

```
INSERT INTO
  C:\Users\ad\Downloads\REFERENCE\Students.adt
(
    LastName
  , FirstMidName
)
VALUES
(
    ?
  , ?
);

select NEWIDSTRING() from system.iota;
```

Apparently the ASP.NET driver for ADS can not handle this form of parameter passing correctly.

The [knowledge base item](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/Content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=070813-1930) you linked to suggest to change the SQL to use named parameters instead:

```
INSERT INTO
  C:\Users\ad\Downloads\REFERENCE\Students.adt
(
    LastName
  , FirstMidName
)
VALUES
(
    :p0
  , :p1
);

select NEWIDSTRING() from system.iota;
```

I don't know enough of NHibernate to tell you how this can be achieved.

Comment: That looks lile a good starting point, maybe there's a way to achieve this with the NHibernate dialect definition. I'll do some further research on this!

Comment: This first workaround did it (modified the driver):
public override void AdjustCommand(DbCommand command)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int pi = 0;
    foreach (var ch in command.CommandText)
    {
        if (ch == '?')
        {
            b.AppendFormat(":p{0}", pi);
            pi++;
        }
        else
        {
            b.Append(ch);
        }
    }
    command.CommandText = b.ToString();
    base.AdjustCommand(command);
}

Comment: @AdRian, the driver can handle named parameters, but it seems its properties currently tell it to use positional parameters instead. Instead of hacking `AdjustCommand`, it should be better to adjust those properties. See by example [the driver for SAP SQL Anywhere](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Driver/SapSQLAnywhere17Driver.cs), which seems to use the same parameter naming than your other SAP database.  
(Is SAP competing for the title of the company selling the greatest number of database systems by the way? They also have HANA, ASE, ...)

Comment: Thank you Frédéric for this very helpful advise! We will test it.
It looks like SAP is leaving the contest you mentioned, the ADS is more or less discontinued since 2015...